# How should I interpret this GCD threading issue message?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

The XCODE TSAN thread analyser is throwing up a threading issue:

`Data race in generic specialization <Foundation.UUID> of Swift._NativeSet.insertNew(_: __owned τ_0_0, at: Swift._HashTable.Bucket, isUnique: Swift.Bool) -> () at 0x10a16b300`

This only occurs in a release build, and its `Data race in generic specialization` that has my attention.

It pin-points the `addID` function. But I cannot see the issue. Here is the relevant code snippet:

```swift
final class IDBox {
    

    let syncQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "IDBox\(UUID().uuidString)", attributes: .concurrent)
    
    private var _box: Set<UUID>
    
    init() {
        self._box = []
    }
    
    var box: Set<UUID> {
        get { syncQueue.sync { self._box } }
        set { syncQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
            self._box = newValue
        }
    }
    
    func addID(_ id: UUID) {
        syncQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
            self._box.insert(id)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was unable to get TSAN to produce any such warning with this code (including multithreaded example adding 100,000 UUIDs to this set). Perhaps you can edit this question to provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...

Comment: To my eye, this looks like a properly implemented reader-writer pattern. If you switch to serial queue (for which the performance is largely indistinguishable), do you get the same TSAN error?

Comment: @Rob Thank you for taking the time to respond and try out the code...after a day away from the screen I found my error. I found a piece of code that made the call 'idBox.box.insert(id) rather than idBox.addId(id)

Comment: I'm genuinely curious how is this possible. My thoughts are: `Set` has value semantics, so if we mutate the value returned by the `box` property, it should get copied without ever mutating the original `_box`. Perhaps I'm missing something fundamental, like maybe the CoW mechanism is making a copy on a wrong queue?

Comment: @VadimBelyaev You are correct. Sorry - in my original code I also had a setter for  the box property as well. I originally excluded it because I thought it wasn't relevant.

Comment: “I found a piece of code that made the call `idBox.box.insert(id)`” … Yeah, that would do it. Good catch. If you think your discovery would be helpful to future readers, then go ahead and [post an answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Otherwise, I might suggest just deleting the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. The read-writer implementation was correct, but I found a call `idBox.box.insert(id)` rather than `idBox.addId(id)` elsewhere in the code base.

As an aside I can see why using an `actor` would prevent this kind of bug...although `actors` come with other constraints, for example not being able to conform to `Codable`. But that's for another post.